# Procedure or term for analyzing transcribed text and returning bulleted output

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, speech-to-text

I am attempting to analyze transcribed text from an audio file to group bullet points based on known key phrases in the text.

Example: I have verbally stated the following keywords in the text, which have explicit meaning and are available in the transcript.

1. Title, followed by a sentence of which I’d like to label this transcript
2. Action, followed by a sentence describing the action I am currently taking
3. Step, followed by multiple sentences of the steps I am taking
4. Result, signaling the end of my steps for the first stated action
5. Final Outcome, closes the loop of actions of the steps within and ultimately wrapping up the title.

I have been careful to only use these keywords during the audio recording to properly bookmark the id of the appropriate section to break apart.

Given this example what I would like to accomplish is an extracted text that starts with the title and has a bullet for each action followed by nested bullets for each of the steps mentioned between the first and second action.

When I use the term final result.  This should end the procedure.

I am not sure how to refer to this form of NLP or if this is even a common ML practice.

---

**Practical Example**

*Input Text (transcribed audio file)*

```
Title debugging some random issue.
Action Investigate the backend server.

I'm now saying random things as fillers and an example of something that should not be captured.

Step I'm now proceeding to analyze the entrypoint for the backend server.

Saying more random things as I'm still within the context of the backend server.

Step I have now tested the entrypoint by using postman to manually trigger api calls.

Result this does not appear to be the problem.

Action Analyzing the front-end client library

Step Review the compiler for errors

Saying more random things as fillers with no context.

Result the compiler appears to be the issue due to a runtime error.

Final Outcome The compiler contained an error resulting in a runtime error. By resolving this matter the parent error is now resolved.
```

*Desired Information Extraction Results*

Title: Debugging Some Random Issue

Actions:

1. Investigate the backend server

   1. I'm now proceeding to analyze the entrypoint for the backend server
   2. I have now tested the entrypoint by using postman to manually trigger api calls
   3. This does not appear to be the problem
2. Analyzing the front-end client library

   1. Review the compiler for errors
   2. The compiler appears to be the issue due to a runtime error.

Result: The compiler appears to be the issue due to a runtime error.
Final Outcome The compiler contained an error resulting in a runtime error.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't understand the 'example' that you give: it looks more like a description of the results you would like, right? Could you provide an actual example of input text with an example of expected output?

Comment: Updated with a practical example

Comment: I don't think this kind of process corresponds to any standard task. At first sight it should be doable, except that automatic sentence segmentation might cause some errors such as 'Step. I'm now proceeding ..', so maybe there will be a bit of adjusting to do at this level. Once the sentences are clean it should be straightforward programming.

Comment: Is there any general name you would give any piece of this procedure.  

I.e Sentiment Analysis, Information Extraction

Comment: From the point of view of NLP, it's a kind of text segmentation guided by 'keywords'. 'keywords' often mean something different so maybe another term would be better, maybe 'signal words'? You could even consider that this a very specific case of sequence labelling (e.g. Named Entity Recognition), but I think this term would be confusing.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. I will do some research around that term.